# Visual C++: использовать один проект в другом в рамках одного решения

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

Т.е. есть решение, в нем два проекта. Один из них библиотека, второй - exe.
Язык c++.
Второму проекту необходим заголовочный файл из первого проекта(т.к. #include ).
Т.е. надо как-то заставить второй проект "увидеть" первый.

Пробовал: связать их так, чтобы они компилировались в нужном порядке. И добавить в Ссылки тоже пробовал.

Еще пытался добавить в каталоги включения и библиотек путь $(SolutionDir)/Release

Comment: "Пробовал: связать их так...", а в чем проблема так и не рассказали...

Comment: Проблема в том, что include продолжает НЕ видеть заголовочный файл.

Comment: В вопрос проблему. Тащемта, ни один препроцессор не ищет файлы на диске везде, он их ищет в указанных каталогах, ниже в ответете написано где устанавливать.

Comment: Я установил каталог для поиска dll. $(SolutionDir)/Release. Файл там есть, его не видит.

Comment: Проблема в том, что "НЕ видеть заголовочный файл", а вы про dll... Конкретную проблему в вопрос пишите.

Comment: Вопрос внимательно прочитайте. Один проект dll, другой exe. Связать dll проекта первого со вторым, т.к. используется include. Ну хорошо, уточню

Comment: Проблема в вопросе отсутствует. Есть "нужно X", это не проблема.

Comment: Я написал, что мне нужно и что я попробовал. Вопрос очевиден.

Comment: Вы, верно, не в понимаете что есть *.h, *.lib и *.dll. На ваш "очевидный" вопрос дан уже очевидный ответ. И он вас не устраивает, что означает неочевидность вопроса.

Answer (score 3):

Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> General -> Additional Include Directories -> добавьте путь к папке с исходниками второго проекта.

Comment: Но мне не исходники нужны. Мне нужно заинклюдить, по сути dll, как в случае с #include <png.h>. Мы же не инклюдим сурцы png.h, а включаем библиотеку.

Comment: Подключение заголовков вам нужно для компиляции. Для запуска пропишите ещё зависимости компоновщика.

Comment: В зависимости от версии студии нужно еще обратить внимание на Debug/Release версию, для которой оные параметры устанавливаются.

Comment: Повторяю. У меня программа, в том числе, требует для КОМПИЛЯЦИИ libpng, но мы сурцы оной не включаем.

Comment: @user64675 если бы вы писали на каком нить C#, то этого было бы достаточно, но в C++ обязательно нужны заголовки.

Comment: Да, нужны. В программе: #include <png.h> и следом #include <first.h>. libpng мы включаем dll-кой, почему бы не включить так и first? У меня же исходников libpng нет, но компилируется.

Comment: @user64675 а откуда по вашему возьмутся эти инклюды? :)

Comment: Из dll, откуда же еще? Повторяю, для libpng работает, из нее берется все что надо.

Comment: @user64675 у меня для вас плохие новости :) Рекомендую почитать про принципы работы компоновщика С++ :)

Comment: @user64675 А вы DLL откройте и посмотрите, есть там искомые инклюды или нет. Нет понимания что есть исходники, и что есть результаты их сборки.

Comment: @user64675: Нет. `#include <png.h>` включает конкретный файл `png.h`, из dll-ки его вытащить невозможно. Он у вас где-то есть, прикиньте!

Comment: (Не пишу я на C/C++, что поделать...) А не получится двойная компиляция? Ну, сначала скомпилировали 1 проект, а затем его же заинклюдили во второй и получается, что второй содержит и первый?

Comment: @user64675 вы можете построить статическую библиотеку, а после подключить ее. Так вы избежите лишних компиляций. А вообще привыкайте к тому, что С++ проекты долго строятся.

Comment: Статическая библиотека это .lib. Динамическая - .dll. Вопрос! Почему же тогда у меня рядом с готовой программой лежит отдельно libpng16.dll? Получается есть способ скомпилить(пусть даже с отдельным .h) проект, который будет юзать динамическую библиотеку и не будет ее дублировать...

Comment: @user64675: Так и есть. Вообще, каждый header компилируется при каждом его инклюде. Поэтому компиляция C++ такая неспешная.

Comment: @user64675 а откуда проект будет знать имя DLL, откуда брать функции и их "внутренние" имена? Из LIB-файлов, либо динамический импорт.

Comment: Хорошо, перефразирую. Как заинклюдить один проект в другой Без использования .lib и дабл-компиляции?
Тем более, что в самой IDE можно связать проекты посредством ссылок.

Comment: @user64675 мне кажется вы не совсем понимаете роль dll. Судя по тому, что у вас солюшен состоит из 2х проектов, вам как раз lib в самый раз.